# AWS Overwirte the S3 file using lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

I have a lambda function which queries Athena and loads the results into S3. My query is like below. Currently, when I run the lambda function twice, I will have 2 files (with random, auto generated names) under an object called 'current_date.csv'. But what I want is the second run can overwrite the first file. Is it possible to overwrite 's3://abc/def/', or what I can do to specify the key (csv file) name? Or is there a way to set the s3 rule saying one object can only has 1 file?

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('athena')

    # Execution
    response = client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString=query,
        QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database': DATABASE
        },
        ResultConfiguration={
            'OutputLocation': 's3://abc/def/current_date.csv',
        }
    )
    return response
    return
```

Comment: It is not creating "multiple files under one object". Each of those files are themselves separate objects. The `OutputLocation` parameter is expected to be a **directory** where the output file(s) will be stored. It is not possible to specify the exact filename (Key) to use.